# Eigenvalue/eigenvector matrix A^(-1)B - Super hard question linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, contest-math

My question is the following: Given that L is an eigenvalue of both A and B with eigenvectors u_1 and u_2, respectively. Is L an eigenvalue of A^(−1)*B? Is this the case? If yes, can the eigenvector of A^(−1)*B be written in terms of u_1 and u_2.

We know that:

- A*(u_1) = L*(u_1)
- B*(u_2) = L*(u_2)

We are looking for:

- A^(-1)B*(u) = L*(u)

And we want to figure out whether L is an eigenvector of this matrix and what the eigenvector would be.

I have tried to manipulate the two equations that we know to the one we are looking for, but I fail to do so. Could it be the case that there is no eigenvalue for that matrix? How would one show that?

Comment: You have included the tag [contest-math]. Is the question you asked a question from a mathematics competition?

Comment: Yes, a practice question for a competition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. For example, consider $L=1$ and the matrices
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&3}.
$$
In general, if there is a question about whether something always holds, it's good to begin by checking whether it holds for simple examples.